# Subquery efficiency regarding WHERE conditions

Tags: mysql

I have a query that includes a subquery within the FROM clause. The structure of the query looks like:

```
SELECT date, avg(total)
FROM(
    SELECT date, id, sum(actions) as total
    FROM table
    WHERE date < '2012-08-07'
    GROUP BY date, id
) subquery
GROUP BY date
```

Is it more efficient to have WHERE conditions such as `WHERE date < '2012-08-07'` to be inside the most inner subquery (as shown) or most outer subquery?

My actual query that I am working with has another outer layer of query, but for the purpose of this question I believe this example will work.

Comment: did you check the `EXPLAIN` plan on both versions?

Answer (score 0):

it depends on the data, but often the date check on the inner subquery should be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know, you can express this without the subquery:

```
SELECT date, sum(total)/count(distinct id)
FROM table
WHERE date < '2012-08-07'
GROUP BY date
```

This may be a bit faster (although `COUNT(DISTINCT)` can be expensive).